# How do I change my Activity's fragment container's background with a custom dialog with code?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

Fairly new to Android and I am trying to do some background color changes. Basically I have a main activity that only has a FrameLayout in it's xml. When the activity is created it opens up a fragment for my program. I have a menu item that when clicked pops a dialog box with 3 seekbars(red, green, blue). I want to change the background color to whatever the seekbars position is. I have all the code finished for the seekbars and I know it works on a simple app I created. For reasons to me unknown my app fails when i try to open the dialog box. What is the proper way to set this up in the Main Activity? I want the user to be able to change the background color whenever they want. All my fragment layouts are transparent. This is the tutorial I have been working off of. http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/08/change-background-color-by-seekbar.html Any advice would be great. I think my problem is I do not fully understand how to access my main_activity's FrameLayout from with-in my MainActivity java class.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#e3a153">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentView"></FrameLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Color_seekbar_selecter.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myScreen"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change color"
        />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mySeekingBar_R"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255"
        android:progress="0"/>
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mySeekingBar_G"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255"
        android:progress="0"/>
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/mySeekingBar_B"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255"
        android:progress="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:title="Green" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_red"
            android:title="Red" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_blue"
            android:title="Blue" />
        <item android:id="@+id/menu_tan"
            android:title="Tan" />



</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //public CategoryFragment categoryFragment;
    //public RecipeFragment recipeFragment;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null)
        {
           CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                   .add(R.id.fragmentView, categoryFragment, "categoryFrag")
                   .commit();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate( R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.menu_green:

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

I have tried for hours to figure this out, but I just don't know where to put what.

This is the code from the example that I found in the link posted above.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class SeekColorActivity extends Activity {

private int seekR, seekG, seekB;
SeekBar redSeekBar, greenSeekBar, blueSeekBar;
LinearLayout mScreen;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mScreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myScreen);
    redSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekingBar_R);
    greenSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekingBar_G);
    blueSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekingBar_B);
    updateBackground();

    redSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
    greenSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
    blueSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

}

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener
= new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
  boolean fromUser) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 updateBackground();
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
};

private void updateBackground()
{
 seekR = redSeekBar.getProgress();
 seekG = greenSeekBar.getProgress();
 seekB = blueSeekBar.getProgress();
 mScreen.setBackgroundColor(
  0xff000000
  + seekR * 0x10000
  + seekG * 0x100
  + seekB
  );
}
}
```

categoryFragment.java

```
package com.example.mikesgamerig.finalproject;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<String> categoryNameArrayList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private AlertDialog alertDialogDelete;
    private EditText categoryEditText;
    private String getCategoryName;
    private List<Category> cats;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //create view
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

        //initialize all variables and widgets
        inflater = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
        alertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_category, null));
        alertDialogDelete = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();
        alertDialogDelete.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_delete_category, null));
        Button buttonAddCategory = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addCategoryButton);
        ListView categoryListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

        //Array list to store names of categories
        categoryNameArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        //List of Category Objects
        cats = Category.listAll(Category.class);

        getCategoryNames();
        //iterate through the CategoryList and attach to the ArrayList


        //create adapter and fill the listView with all the name of categories
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, categoryNameArrayList);
        categoryListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //set OnClick listener for the add category Button.
        // This calls another method that will open a custom dialog box
        buttonAddCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DisplayAddCategoryDialogBox();
            }
        });

        //set an onItemLongClick listener for the ListView.
        //First have to setLongClickable to true.
        //the OnItemLongClick listener will call a method to open a custom Dialog to delete a category.
        categoryListView.setLongClickable(true);
        categoryListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                DeleteCategory(i);
                return true;
            }
        });

        //opens up a new fragment with a list of recipes for the specific category.
        categoryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                String name = categoryNameArrayList.get(i);
                RecipeFragment fragment = new RecipeFragment();
                fragment.SetTitleName(name);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentView, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();


            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }

//This method will Display a custom add category Dialog Box.
    public void DisplayAddCategoryDialogBox(){

        //Show the Dialog box to enter a new category name.
        alertDialog.show();
        categoryEditText = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.categoryEditText);
        Button saveCategoryDialogBtn = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        Button cancelDialogButton = (Button) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);
        saveCategoryDialogBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getCategoryName = categoryEditText.getText().toString();
                //Log.d("STRING VALUE:", getCategoryName);
                Category test = new Category(getCategoryName);
                test.save();
                categoryNameArrayList.add(test.getName());
                //Log.d("added Value: ", test.getName());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                alertDialog.hide();
            }
        });

        cancelDialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertDialog.hide();
            }
        });

    }

//this method will display a custom Delete Category Alert Dialog box.
    public void DeleteCategory(final int i)
    {
        alertDialogDelete.show();
        Button noBtn = (Button) alertDialogDelete.findViewById(R.id.noBtn);
        noBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alertDialogDelete.hide();
            }
        });
        Button yesBtn = (Button) alertDialogDelete.findViewById(R.id.yesBtn);
        yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String tempString = categoryNameArrayList.get(i);
                //Log.d("VALUE OF STRING= ", tempString);
                categoryNameArrayList.remove(i);
                for (Category category : cats) {
                    String name = category.getName();
                    if (name.equals(tempString)) {
                        category.delete();
                    }
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                alertDialogDelete.hide();
            }
        });


    }

    //Filles the Array
    public void getCategoryNames()
    {
        for(Category category : cats)
        {
            String name = category.getName();

            categoryNameArrayList.add(name);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: can you show the CategoryFragment.java

Comment: I posted my fragment.  Everything works properly for its purpose.  This color selection is just me being picky about how my app looks

Comment: I see you did not still implemented the dialog with seek bar that change the background color of your fragment. The main activity has menu options but I can not see in to the menu click open the seek bar dialog. let me know what help you need. I think you can open the dialog on menu item and you can sure change the background color of your fragment.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  My trouble is I am not really sure how to set this up.  I know in a fragment I initialize all of my variables in the onCreate and use them like I did in the categoryFragment, setting onclicks and a few methods here and there.  Witht the main, I dont really understand how to set it up.  I understand fragments, but activities confuse me i guess.  I have tried many different ways and it all seems to end with the result of a crash either when the fragment loads or when the dialog alert is opened.  I hope this clears it up for you

Comment: Should I not be using the Main Activity for this?

Comment: No You can use the main activity, in main activity menu item open the seekbar dialog that will change the background of your fragment.